# ARP table Flag field in hotspot

Tags: android, arp, hotspot

Below is a sample row which I am getting from ARP table (of course the side names were putted by me):

> IP::192.168.43.184::HW typ::0x1 :: Flags::0x0::HW address::70:bb:c0:bb:99:66 :: Mask:: *::Device::wlan0*

I saw the `Flag` field became `0x2` the moment a device gets connected and it became `0x0` when it gets disconnected (this one does not happen momentarily).

I need to know what the `Flag` field really means. Is this field really a solid hint to be notified whenever a device is connected to hotspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218732/1259540) I got few hints about the `Flag`. Here [Amap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4353178/amap) said:

> FLAGS field, when the value is 0x2 the station is connected and 0x0 is disconnected

I am relying on this `Flag` for the time being. Yet it is highly appreciated if someone can confirm about the reliability of this field.