# How to get details of devices connected to Mobile WiFi Hotspot

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

Following the answers of [Wi-Fi tethering - how to get list of connected clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996351/wi-fi-tethering-how-to-get-list-of-connected-clients), I have got the list of devices which are connected to my Mobile WiFi Hotspot by reading `/proc/net/arp` file, which works for both rooted and non-rooted devices.

Now, I want to get the details of the devices connected, such as SSID, Device Type, etc.

From the `arp` file, I have logged following :

```
[IP, address, HW, type, Flags, HW, address, Mask, Device]
[ip.ip.ip.ip, 0x1, 0x2, ma:ma:ma:ma:ma:ma, *, wlan0]
```

Clearly, I'm not getting any more details other than *IP Address*, *MAC Address*, *Device Connection*.

So, if I want to get more details on the devices connected to my Mobile WiFi Hotspot, how should I approach?

Comment: What other details are you expecting?

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Like I said, SSID and Device Type are my main concerns.